# Forloop through input's and retrieve the value

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, laravel

i have this problem:

When i forloop through 50 input's and i only filled in the first input the request / post returns `null`. But when i fill in the last input it returns the value.

Controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get('type');

    $country = Country::create([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'country' => $data['name']
    ]);
}
```

And this is the form

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="/form" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        @for($x = 0; $x++ < 50;)
            <input type="text" name="type[name]">
        @endfor

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need array input,  change this `<input type="text" name="type[name]">` for this `<input type="text" name="type[name][]">` in you controller you must go through the input array that will arrive to insert in your model

Comment: Hmm oke that works, but the case i have is that i have 2 inputs, type[id] and type[name]. How would i catch that in the controller ?

Comment: So you have 50 inputs or two inputs?

Comment: 50 inputs, 50 inputs of id and 50 of name

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I have no clue how i could split those apart so i can save them to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i combined the answers from @ravinder and @u_mulder. This the solution that worked for me.

The form:

```
<form action="/form" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
@for($x = 0; $x++ < 50;)
    <input type="text" name="type[{{$x}}][id]">
    <input type="text" name="type[{{$x}}][name]">
@endfor
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

The controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->type as $value) {
        if(!empty($value['id']) && !empty($value['name'])) { // if they are not empty proceed
            $country = Country::create([ // Create a country
                'user_id' => $value['id'],
                'country' => $value['name'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help guys !

Answer (score 2):

Your input name is not correct. If you want to have multiple inputs with same name, you have declare it as an array.

In Html Replace

```
{{csrf_field()}}
@for($x = 0; $x++ < 50;)
    <input type="text" name="type[name]">
@endfor
```

with

```
{{csrf_field()}}
@for($x = 0; $x++ < 50;)
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="id[]"> // since you said you have two inputs
@endfor
```

In your controller

Loop the input array and add code to insert it to database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $names = $request->get('name');  // get posted name array
    $ids = $request->get('id');  // get posted id array
    if(!empty($id) && !empty($name)){  // validations
      foreach($names as $key=>$value){
         // you can add more validations here
         $country = Country::create([
            'user_id' => $ids[$key],
            'country' => $value
         ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to understand what are you trying to achieve but:

```
<form action="/form" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @for($x = 0; $x++ < 50;)
        <input type="text" name="type[{{$x}}][id]">
        <input type="text" name="type[{{$x}}][name]">
    @endfor

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is your form. Set indexes in `name` attribute **explicitly**. In this case your `$request->type` will look like:

```
array(
    0 => array(id => value0, name => value0)
    1 => array(id => value1, name => value1)
    // more items
)
```

In controller you can iterate over it:

```
foreach ($request->type as $value) {
    $country = Country::create([
        // don't know where you should put id, but
        'id_key' => $value['id'],
        'country' => $value['name'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Yep this work's good solution ! Now i have to find out what to do when the $value is empty.

Comment: Check with `empty` and do not insert if name or id is empty.